# How to create boxes with description fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently having a small problem with some CSS/JS logic around creating a box inside-ish of a box. JsFiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/pa7wt2g3/

I want to create 1 box and upon clicking the box, create a description field under it. however currently the description fields are all appering inside the first box when making additional boxes.

I suspect I have to give every box an uniqe ID which is later used to specifiy where to put the description area, but how do I go about this?

```js
function textarea() { // Toggles dropdown and sets the dropdown and textfield as the same width as the created div
  document.getElementById('dropdown').classList.toggle("show");
  style = window.getComputedStyle(crtdiv);
  wdt = style.getPropertyValue('width');
  dropdown.style.width = wdt;
}

  document.getElementById("läggatill").onclick = function () { // Run function when läggatill is clicked
  var div = document.createElement('div'); // create div element
  div.className = 'newrect'; // apply css
  div.setAttribute("id", "crtdiv");

  var button = document.createElement('button'); // create button element
  button.setAttribute("id", "hej"); // Giving an id
  var buttontext = document.createTextNode("X"); // Sets the button value
  button.appendChild(buttontext); // Shows the value of the button
  button.className = 'hej'; // apply css
  button.setAttribute("onClick", "removeDiv(this)"); // runs the removeDiv funtion

  var dropdown = document.createElement('dropdown'); // create dropdown element
  dropdown.setAttribute("id", "dropdown"); // Giving an id
  dropdown.className = 'dropdown'; //apply css
  div.setAttribute("onClick","textarea()"); // Run textarea funtion

  var ptext = document.createElement('p'); // create p element
  var textnode = document.createTextNode("Add description"); // Sets the innerText of the p element
  ptext.appendChild(textnode); // Shows the InnerText
  ptext.className = 'text'; // apply css
  ptext.setAttribute("id", "text"); // Giving an id
  
  var textfield = document.createElement('Textarea'); // create textarea element
  textfield.className = 'autoExpand'; // apply css
  textfield.setAttribute("id", "textfield"); // Giving an id
 
  var text = document.getElementById("myText").value; //take the value of the text field
  div.innerHTML = text; // show text in the div
  if (text === "") { // Shows every element if the textfield has text in it
      return 0; // Returns nothing if the text field is empty
  } else { 
      document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].appendChild(div).appendChild(button);
      document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].appendChild(dropdown); 
      document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0].appendChild(ptext);
      document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown')[0].appendChild(textfield);
  }
};
function removeDiv(elem) { // Removes div when pressing the button
  $(elem).parent('div').remove();
}
```

```css
/* Start of lägga till kompetens */
  
.newrect {
  min-width: 55px;
  max-width: 195px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  padding: 1% 3%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none; 
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute !important;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 0.96%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.show { 
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

          <input id="myText" type="text" class="skriv" name="Kompetenser" autocomplete="off" autofocus> <!-- Textfield for kompetenser -->
          <input id="läggatill" class="läggatill" type="button" value="Add box"> <!-- Button lägga till -->

<span style="display:block;"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A couple of things: Note that jsFiddle has a box just for JavaScript code. Putting the code in a script tag in the HTML section seems a bit odd. Secondly, adding event handlers via attributes using `setAttribute("onClick", ` seems a bit backwards. You're in JavaScript; just attach the event handler using JavaScript. Finally please provide a [mre] in the question itself, rather than only on an external site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do pretty much everything jsFiddle provides here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Why is your question tagged with [tag:jquery] since you're not using any jQuery?

Comment: Hi, @lucke111222!
 First of all: you are creating **multiple elements with same id**, that's not recommended at all because id's (despite you can have multiple same) are meant to be unique in your page. You may want to use classes instead...
 You want to add a tag with some text you get by the input above. And when you click this tag you want to show a textarea (the description field) right below the tag box it is associated, right?
 When I click one tag box, should all the description fields show up too? Or just the one associated with the tag box clicked?

Comment: @gpaulini Thanks for the feedback. I want to add a box with the text from the input above. When that is done I want to be able to click on the box and that should create/show another field that works as a "description" for the formentioned box. When clicking on the box only that boxs description/dropdown should show. Just the one associated with the tag box clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct - all IDs must be unique. In order to achieve this, you'll have to refactor a large portion of your code. For example, the `textarea` function is triggered by clicking on the added boxes - that's fine. The problem is that the function isn't aware of which box was actually clicked - it refers to an element with a fixed ID "dropdown". Since there are multiple elements with the same ID, it has no way of knowing which box needs to be expanded. 
You could simply pass `this` as an argument to this function and refer to the context, but then you'd have to account for the fact that you're using a global variable `dropbox` declared outside of the function's scope.

I've rewritten the whole thing. That's how I would implement this feature. I saw you're using jQuery in a few lines, hence my code largely depends on it. If you can't use jQuery in your final project, let me know, I'll post a version in pure vanilla JS. I also had to make some tiny CSS changes (flexbox).

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/zLm2x5k6/

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    //You can use IDs here because these elements are unique
    const $addBtn = $("#läggatill");
    const $inputBox = $("#myText");
    const $flexBox = $("#flexbox");

    $addBtn.click(() => {
        //Creating a new box that contains everything we need and saving it to a variable
        //I'm using ES6 template strings to embed the value of $inputBox
        const $box = $(`
            <div class="box">
                <div class="newrect">
                    ${$inputBox.val()}
                    <button class="hej">X</button>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <p class="text" id="text">Add description</p>
                <textarea class="autoExpand"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        `);
        //Adding event listeneres for the box elements
        $box.find(".hej").click(function () {
            //Removing the parent .box wrapper DIV
            $(this).closest(".box").remove();
        });
        $box.find(".newrect").click(() => {
            const $dropdown = $box.find(".dropdown");
            //If the dropdown is invisible, show it. Otherwise, hide it
            if ($dropdown.css("display") === "none") {
                $box.find(".dropdown").show();
            } else {
                $box.find(".dropdown").hide();
            }
        });

        //Appending the box to the flexBox
        $box.appendTo($flexBox);
    });
});
```

```css
html, body { /* So you can adjust height */
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Start of lägga till kompetens */
  
.newrect {
  min-width: 105px;
  max-width: 195px;
  margin-top: 1%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-left: 1%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.flexbox{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.skriv {
  border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 2%;
  width: 51%; 
  margin: 2%;
}

.läggatill {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 2% 5%;
  width: 23%;
  max-width: 200px;
  float: right;
}

.dropdown {
  display: none; 
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 0.96%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
}
.dropdown textarea{
  width: 100px;
}


.show { 
  display: block; 
} 

.hej {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: darkblue;
}

.autoExpand {
  /* display: none;  */
  /* position: absolute !important; */
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 0.96%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 0;
  resize: none;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30%;
  cursor: default;
}

/* End of lägga till kompetens */
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Profil.css"> <!-- Länk till CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="myText" type="text" class="skriv" name="Kompetenser" autocomplete="off" autofocus> <!-- Textfield for kompetenser -->
  <input id="läggatill" class="läggatill" type="button" value="Add box"> <!-- Button lägga till -->
  <div class="flexbox" id="flexbox"></div> <!-- Container for the boxes -->
  <span style="display:block;">
  
  </span>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

there!
I've also worked in a solution and I would like to share it.
It is very similar to what @Tomasz Kasperczyk answered, I've rewritten your code using jQuery and added some flexbox features to the CSS (plus some classes I renamed so I wouldn't confuse myself). 
It's more simplified now and working. I hope it is easy for you to understand.

```js
function addTagBox(text) {
  var $tagBox = $($('#tagBoxTemplate').html());
  $tagBox.find('.tagBox-label').text(text);
  $('#tagsContainer').append($tagBox);
}

$('#addTagBoxButton').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var tagName = $('#myText').val();

  if (tagName.length) {
    addTagBox(tagName);
  }
})


//listeners for the dynamic elemtens
$('#tagsContainer').on('click', '.tagBox', function(evt) {
  $('.tagBox-dropdown').removeClass('dropdown--isVisible');
  $(this).find('.tagBox-dropdown').toggleClass('dropdown--isVisible');
})

$('#tagsContainer').on('click', '.tagBox-destroy', function(evt) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

```css
html,
body {
  /* So you can adjust height */
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#tagsContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.tagBox {
  min-width: 55px;
  max-width: 195px;
  margin: 0 1rem 2rem 0;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
  border-radius: 40px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#myText {
  border-radius: 40px;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0 2%;
  width: 51%;
  margin: 2%;
}

.addTagBoxButton {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  outline: none;
  margin: 2% 5%;
  width: 23%;
  max-width: 200px;
  float: right;
}

.tagBox-dropdown {
  display: none;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(100% + 5px);
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown--isVisible {
  display: block;
}

.tagBox-destroy {
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  color: darkblue;
}

.tagBox-dropdown-textarea {
  margin-top: 10%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  margin-left: 0.96%;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 0;
  resize: none;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30%;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body>
  <input id="myText" type="text" name="Kompetenser" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
  <input id="addTagBoxButton" class="addTagBoxButton" type="button" value="Add box">

  <div id="tagsContainer"></div>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>

  <template id="tagBoxTemplate">
 <div class="tagBox">
  <span class="tagBox-label"></span>
  <button class="tagBox-destroy">X</button>
  <div class="tagBox-dropdown">
   <textarea name="description" class="tagBox-dropdown-textarea" placeholder="Type some description here"></textarea>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

</body>

</html>
```

PS: for the tag boxes I opted for wrapping its base structure in a [template element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) so it does not mess our JS code with HTML (this is very subjective though). And I linked the JS to an external file.